# Validation of Selected Dimension and Metrics in Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are currently using Adobe Analytics API's and inside that we require validation of dimensions and metrics in order to know whether the combination of dimension and metric is possible or not, so for that earlier we were using v1.4 Report.Validate API which use to give us the desired result but now we are currently using v2 version api, so does anybody have an idea how we can achieve this in v2 version API.

[@AdobeSwagger](https://adobedocs.github.io/analytics-2.0-apis/?client_id=5a8dcc2cfa71472cbfa4fb53671c45ed&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dSI6Imltc19uYTEta2V5LTEuY2VyIn0.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.XWR2x7zY53jKq0mwbr-hooeU2yRYqNh_cDb2xnlINwXcejO5rG-lqXubsCpUySlua4XTpVhmjuH0b44UQXi1bFhsqIQnnfXbT3GV6664VAvXMtGPzk8VfjFmY2yDTZ41Bqu3IdOTdNu7I5Q4JAT_Vl0TXGAzAxiNckFVjMX4nt6wk7kG11JOrcuc0HWCOb4RD6g3dpEl-hlLJXrQlU-dHqxL0FhANQ-FNNEEmC3Be2lXspKOza9qB6jrol_qvyjRpE2X8jAUrhEQttR2j-PjDQStupDpQ9JCuYffjGg-kr1zVZuWuGh5zGbH-uKeR0jpzE6Uqg0PvrDqdzU-Ce8ZhA&gc_ids=exchan232&company_names=Exchange%20Alteryx#/) [@AdobeAnalytics](https://www.adobe.io/apis/experiencecloud/analytics/api-reference.html#!AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/master/docs/swagger.json)

Thank You!

Comment: You probably already looked, but just 2nd pair of eyeing for you.. I do not see that this is currently available in API v2 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2.0 API you generally shouldn't have issues with bad metric or dimension combinations. When you [get a list of dimensions](https://developer.adobe.com/analytics-apis/docs/2.0/apis/#tag/dimensions) for a report you can see if the dimension is valid in a report or a segment, but I believe that by default it only gives you valid dimensions and metrics for reporting.

The validation option could also be used to check if your request was well formed, but for that use case you should get an error pretty quickly if you try and run the report.